# post increment vs +1 in recursive function

Tags: java, recursion, backtracking

I was working on [Leetcode #22 Generate Parentheses.](https://leetcode.com/problems/generate-parentheses/) In one of their solutions, I noticed if we change `open+1` and `close+1` to `++open` and `++close`, the code doesn't work anymore. I thought we could still use pre-increment in recursion, so I don't understand what makes the difference here.

```
class Solution {
    public List<String> generateParenthesis(int n) {
        List<String> ans = new ArrayList();
        backtrack(ans, new StringBuilder(), 0, 0, n);
        return ans;
    }

    public void backtrack(List<String> ans, StringBuilder cur, int open, int close, int max){
        if (cur.length() == max * 2) {
            ans.add(cur.toString());
            return;
        }

        if (open < max) {
            cur.append("(");
            backtrack(ans, cur, open+1, close, max);
            cur.deleteCharAt(cur.length() - 1);
        }
        if (close < open) {
            cur.append(")");
            backtrack(ans, cur, open, close+1, max);
            cur.deleteCharAt(cur.length() - 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you change `open+1` in `backtrack(ans, cur, open+1, close, max)` to `++open` you change the value that is tested in the `if (close < open)` condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference between passing value using `++open` and `open+1` is that in the former, the value of the variable `open` is changed, while in the latter it is not. That is,

- If open is, say 2, after `++open`, the value of `open` is `3`
- However, when you do `open+1`, you only pass `3` but the value of `open` is still `2`. So, the next loop gets the same value.

To better understand, the following is equivalent to `++open`:

```java
backtrack(ans, cur, (open = open+1), close, max);
```

In the above code, the bracketed expression is evaluated to set the value of `open` to `open+1` before being passed to the method.